# How to track the scroll event of individual cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: angular, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to build pagination scroll in my app. I have two instances of `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`, Want to track individual scroll events and make API call for the individual scrolls. How to achieve that?

[image]
Stackblitz URL
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-programatically-scroll-uqgvpu?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@ViewChild` with each component selector.

First in HTML template, declare a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax) for each component, by using hash symbol and name on component tag :

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #cmp1 itemSize="50".../>
```

Then use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator in order to query component, and be able to reference it inside code :

```js
@ViewChild('cmp1') cmp1: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once we register virtual scroll child inventory element

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false })
```

We can subscribe on the elementScrolled observable,

```
this.cmp1.elementScrolled()
   .subscribe(event => {
    console.log('scrolled');
});
```